# Is alt="" ONLY readable for images?

Tags: html, seo, alt

I would like to use the alt attribute so I can use it for my search widget in WordPress.

I am using elementor and WordPress editor so I can add the attributes with HTML.

```html
<h3 alt="seawater">seawater</h3>
```

I tried this code and went to my search widget but the results weren't what I expected.

I know I can use YOAST plugin so maybe I should dig into that instead.
I would like to do an SEO for the paragraphs that are important on the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "alt" attribute is used as an alternative information for an image if for some reason that image can't be loaded or if the user is using a screen reader.

For img tags, "alt" attribute is required.

You can also use it with area and input tags.

Regarding your question about SEO and Heading Tags, I think you should take a look at best practices about it. How and When to use them really matters if you're worried about SEO.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm going to use that plug in instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use alt only for `<area>`, `<img>` and `<input>` tags.